# Rota no Google Maps utilizando coordenadas

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho este código para criação de rotas utilizando Google Maps

```js
var map;
var directionsDisplay; // Instanciaremos ele mais tarde, que será o nosso     google.maps.DirectionsRenderer
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); // Instanciando...
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);

  var options = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map); // Relacionamos o directionsDisplay com o mapa desejado
}

initialize();

$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var enderecoPartida = $("#txtEnderecoPartida").val();
  var enderecoChegada = $("#txtEnderecoChegada").val();

  var request = { // Novo objeto google.maps.DirectionsRequest, contendo:
    origin: enderecoPartida, // origem
    destination: enderecoChegada, // destino
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING // meio de transporte, nesse caso, de carro
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { // Se deu tudo certo
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result); // Renderizamos no mapa o resultado
    }
  });
});
```

Eu encontrei este código no link [Blog PrinciWeb](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-criando-rotas-entre-multiplos-pontos.html)

Eu preciso usar a rota utilizando coordenadas diretamente, sem utilizar Geoprocessamento para converter as coordenadas em endereço.

Comment: Você pode passar a lat/lng para as propriedades `origin` e `destination`, não precisa ser necessariamente um endereço (String). Veja mais na documentação do [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=pt-br#DirectionsRequest).

Comment: Obrigado Douglas, estava procurando esta documentação.

Comment: Ok, vou deixar isso como resposta então. Só marcar como a correta fazendo favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme eu havia comentado, não é necessário passar para as propriedades `origin` e `destination` um endereço (String), você pode passar latitude e longitude.

Para maiores esclarecimentos, favor verificar a [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=pt-br#DirectionsRequest).